# Infinite redirect with AliasMatch apache

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I'm getting infinite redirects with `AliasMatch /hira/.*[^/] "/var/www/html/hira"`

If anyone knows why that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

What is the `DocumentRoot` set as? If `DocumentRoot` is set as `/var/www/html`, the default for many distributions, why are you using any Alias directive for /hira?

[Apache Alias Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias)

Comment: `Alias /hira/search "/var/www/html/hira"` works, so I though I'd follow the same format but with AliasMatch. It just keeps going `/index.html/index.html/*`

Comment: In that case, looks like there is a variable missing at the end of the file system path, e.g. `AliasMatch "^/hira/(.*)$" "/var/www/html/hira/$1"`

Comment: See [apache AliasMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch)

Comment: but wouldn't `"/var/www/html/hira/$1"` match whatever `(.*)` got? I want anything after `/hira` to redirect to `/hira` only

Comment: It would, I think what you want is a `Rewrite` such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735720/how-to-mod-rewrite-all-requests-to-single-file-without-causing-an-infinite-loop) e.g.
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/hira`
`RewriteRule .* /hira [R=Permanent,L]`